# GitHub Action Is not pushing image to dockerhub

Tags: docker, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

So I wanted to look into CI and wrote a github workflow to publish my image to dockerhub with the latest tag when pushing a commit and with release when I publish a release. So far so good, it seemed to be working, everything ran successfuly. But it never actually reached dockerhub, the image is just nowhere to found.

The action looks like this:

```
name: Build and push docker images

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  build_and_push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      # Prevent a failure in one image from stopping the other builds
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        include:
          - context: "server"
            image: "matrix-notifier-server"
            platforms: "linux/arm/v6,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/amd64"
          - context: "bot"
            image: "matrix-notifier-bot"
            platforms: "linux/arm/v6,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/amd64"
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2.1.0

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2.4.1
        
      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
          
      - name: Generate docker image tags
        id: metadata
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          flavor: |
            latest=false
          images: |
            name=nlion/${{matrix.image}}
          tags: |
            # Tag with latest
            type=raw,value=latest,enable=${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}
            # Tag with git tag on release
            type=ref,event=tag,enable=${{ github.event_name == 'release' }}
            
      - name: Build and push image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4.0.0
        with:
          context: ${{ matrix.context }}
          platforms: ${{ matrix.platforms }}
          tags: ${{ steps.metadata.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.metadata.outputs.labels }}
```

Building and pushing manually as I've always done works perfectly fine, so im lead to believe that something is wrong with the action.

Comment: If you want to push latest tag, you should probably trigger on `push.tags` instead of a branch, no? As for what's wrong: are there any logs?

Comment: Well, I dont knwo what exactly you're talking about with push.tags. I want to push to push the image to the docker hub whenever I push something to the main branch or I make a release and it that case it should push the image with the tag of the release. But (correct me if im wrong) I believe that should be working just fine, however my problem is that is does not push the things to the hub after building them. And for the logs well thats what I found so strange. No errors nothing. From the logs you'd think the image was pushed to the hub just fine.

Comment: With `push.tags` I meant to trigger on push, but for specific tags instead of the main branch, but if it triggers fine the way you have it, never mind. I think you miss `push: true` in the `build-push-action` settings (see [list](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#inputs)).

Comment: Actually push: true might be right, and im gonna try that in just a second but it doesnt seem like other people are using that, look here for example: https://github.com/immich-app/immich/actions/runs/4332280794/workflow They dont seem to be using that, but it still works fine, or am I missing something?

Comment: Alright so `push: true` actually fixed it but I still dont understand why it works for other people.

Comment: They do use it, [here](https://github.com/immich-app/immich/actions/runs/4332280794/workflow#L105), but instead of `true`, they use `${{ !github.event.pull_request.head.repo.fork }}` to only push when the pull request is not from a fork.

Comment: Oh I see thanks for explaining and helping me out here.